# How to add brand logo to email accounts?

Tags: html, email, gravatar

I have been looking to add a contact image of our business to our emails and I cannot seem to get it to pull up. I have experimented with gmail outlook etc and no look. I have assign a profile image but have received no luck. I do receive emails from Home Depot, Best Buy and see the brand images assigned to the emails I receive.

Any thoughts or ideas?

I feel like I should be able to add some sort of header tag to have this appear?
[image]

Comment: "see the brand images assigned to the emails I receive" — Where do you see them? In which email clients?

Comment: Primarily in Gmail as this is where most of our clients are using. But I am also using outlook and and bluemail. @Quentin